# Issue in generating D3 chart in angular2 component

Tags: d3.js, angular, angular2-services

I tried creating a angular2 service which would read the json file and return the contents which would be consumed by the component and draw a bubble-chart using D3.
The http service is returning me the json contents but there is some issue in generating D3 bubblechart. I am not able to get the exact error for not generating the chart in plunker.   My [plunker url](https://plnkr.co/edit/05NgbDOA2oSsw58fHRDs?p=preview)

But when I tried in my localhost, the chrome browser gives me the error as below

```
angular2-polyfills.js:487 Unhandled Promise rejection: EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    at new BubbleChartComponent (http://localhost:55568/appScripts/BubbleChartComponent.js:18:22)
    at AppView._View_BubbleChartComponent_Host0.createInternal (BubbleChartComponent_Host.template.js:20:36)
    at AppView.create (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2.dev.js:22641:23)
    at ComponentFactory.create (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2.dev.js:7668:34)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2.dev.js:8215:40
    at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2.dev.js:8192:20
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2-polyfills.js:349:29)
    at Object.onInvoke (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2.dev.js:2185:31)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2-polyfills.js:348:35)
    at Zone.run (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2-polyfills.js:242:44)
```

any idea what is it I am missing?

Comment: What does your `BubbleChartComponent` look like?

Comment: the working version of my D3 bubble chart without any service (by directly reading from the json file) can be found in the link https://embed.plnkr.co/qM3qrk3swvalQFBh1Db1/

Comment: load your D3.js before load angular2. Btw I endup with something other XMLHTTP error. good luck.

Comment: You need to install the definition files of d3 for typescript then import d3 as a module.